# jQuery fadeIn fadeOut image difference 1px in Firefox

Tags: jquery, image, firefox, fadein, fadeout

i've recently been implementing an image slider using jQuery.

So i have a problem in Firefox where the FadeIn/FadeOut transitions would shorten the width or height of my images by 1 px. but only while the effect is in progress.

once the progress is done, the image had full dimensions again

Answer (score 14):

Found it.

add this style to your image and it will be solved on FF.

```
box-shadow: #000 0em 0em 0em;
```

for some reason unknown to me yet this is the fix. 
Bug in FireFox.