# 1px glitch in jquery slider

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, responsive-slides

With every slide transition, the image loads 1px up and to the left, then repositions itself in place when the transition is complete.

I think the issue is in the CSS/layout of the website.

This is only happening in firefox.

When I test the slider in a preview mode (isolated environment, just the slider in a pop up), there is no problem. So I don't think it has to do with the javascript.

It's a Wordpress site. Metaslider Plugin. on "R. Slides" (based on responsiveslides.com).

Any ideas?

It's happening in my "stages/locations" section [here](http://bfpstaging.brooklynfireproofstages.com/#stageslocations) Under sections "Stage A" through "Support/Locations"

Comment: You are right. It may only be a firefox issue.

Comment: seems like half the issues on SO are firefox issues.  that browser is just garbage!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to the img tag and adding an exact width in pixels corrected this problem.

```
box-shadow: #000 0em 0em 0em;
```

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289109/jquery-fadein-fadeout-image-difference-1px-in-firefox). Similar 1px glitch problem with an image slider and firefox.