# Weird animation bug in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a site that uses .animate() to slide an image up to its correct position using the "top" css property. The animation starts and stops properly but I noticed that when the animation completes there is a slight pause and then it looks like the image gets shifted one pixel to the right.

Its almost like the image gets shifted 1 pixel left when the animation starts and then when its done it moves back. Has anyone else seen this before and knows how to fix it?

```
function animPicture(imageNum) {
    if(imageNum != currentImage) {
        $(imageNum).css("top", "-312px");
        $(currentImage).stop(true, false).animate({ top: "312px" }).css("z-index", "100");
        $(imageNum).stop(true, false).animate({ top: "0px" }).css("z-index", "99");
        currentImage = imageNum;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: please post some code example, preferably like a fiddle

Comment: Maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289109/jquery-fadein-fadeout-image-difference-1px-in-firefox

Comment: adding box-shadow: #000 0em 0em 0em; didn't help

Comment: just kidding it did!